# Baking PI with C and basic libs

Tags: c, assembly, arm, mingw, yagarto

I have following problem - I've done baking pi course without any problems and then I 've decided to link this pure asm with some C. And I have done this and everything is working nice as far as I decided to use function sprintf to  convert int to char*. Now when im trying to compile im enjoying following error

`ctesty.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'sprintf'
make: *** [build/output.elf] Error 1`

of course i have included stdio.h, i also tried to include this lib directly in makefile but without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to link with `libc.so`. Try adding `-lc` in the link step in your makefiles.

**Update after Better Understanding of the Question**

The [Baking Pi](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/) examples build a `kernel.img` that runs in place of the usual Linux kernel. This means that the C standard library is not available. You'll need to supply your own `sprintf()` implementation, e.g.:

- Adapt this BSD licensed [ee_printf.c](https://github.com/jpbonn/coremark_lm32/blob/master/ee_printf.c)
- Remove `uart_send_char()`
- Adapt `ee_printf()` into `sprintf()` by making `buf` a function parameter

**Why a Userspace libc Wouldn't Work Without Source Modifications in any Kernel**

Conceptually:

- The C standard library contains facilities dealing with dynamic memory allocation (`malloc`, `free`), the file system (`fopen`, `fclose` and all of stdio), environment variables (`getenv`), error handling facilities like `setjmp` `longjmp` and more.
- Consider: how would you implement `malloc` in a program running under an operating system?

  - Answer: You'd need some interface to request additional memory from the OS, such as `brk`, `sbrk` and `mmap` under Linux.
  - In an OS kernel, `brk`, `mmap` etc wouldn't be the right interfaces to allocate memory.
  - Thus though most non-toy kernels provide `malloc` like facilities, they won't be able to use the userspace `malloc` implementations unmodified.
- In an OS kernel, functions like `fopen`, `getenv` are not really that useful. Most kernel writers choose not to include them.
- Thus most kernels don't include complete C standard library implementations but only the functions that the kernel writers find useful.

In a more mechanical sense:

- The [Baking Pi Makefile](http://pastebin.com/hvW2TmAA) produces the kernel ELF image with the command `$(ARMGNU)-ld --no-undefined $(OBJECTS) -Map $(MAP) -o $(BUILD)output.elf -T $(LINKER)`. This doesn't link `build/output.elf` with any libc implementation so the linker wouldn't be able to find a symbol named `sprintf`.
- When you build a program with `gcc T.c -o T`, gcc implicitly links in libc unless an option like `-nostdlib` is passed.

But the conceptually important points are:

- The parts of the C standard library that are useful in a kernel would require different implementations
- A lot of other parts of libc wouldn't be that useful in a kernel

There are C standard library implementations targeting bare metal environments. See for example, [newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/).

Comment: not sure how it may help, other libs like stdlib.h works perfect only with sprintf (for now) I have problem I will try maybe some other functions from this lib and give an response. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Macko, showing the commands you're using to build and link your program would help you get a better answer.

Comment: im using standart baking pi course makefile [link]http://pastebin.com/hvW2TmAA  itoa not working too.

Comment: @Macko, I've updated my answer to explain that you need to supply your own `sprintf` and how to do so

Comment: thanks, I have already written my own function to workaround, but I just wondering why these functions doesnt working and I still dunno, can u explain why i cant use them while building kernel? Sorry Im new in bare metal.